# VBA coding regarding to data sorting

Tags: vba

Having big data for different departments, require to do monthly update on them.
Each time when the data is updated I need to sort them to different departments.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code. What do you mean by ``I need to sort them to different departments.``?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search stackoverflow.com. There are multiple questions of similar types which have been answered.

Besides you can also try to record a macro and edit it to suit your needs.